# How to implement friend add/remove functionality in an iOS app using parse database?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, database, parse-platform

I am trying to implement functionality to store data about user's friends (request friend, received friend request, accepted request). I have two tables.

First table is _User with username column.

Second table is Friends. This table is keeping track of who are friends of the user. This table has two fields:

1. A pointer column to user table
2. An array column called receivedRequest. In this array I keep the _User's objectId who are send request to that user.

Table _User has one to one relation with Friends table but meanwhile there is an array field keeping information of user's friend. In this array I am saving objectId of other users. I am using an array to avoid repeating rows for each friend's request.

Fist I want to know if this is a good idea or there is any alternative better that this. Actually I have extra array columns which is recived requests. Send requests. And accepted requests. All of them are array.

Second I want to know how can I write a query to go to Friends table. Find current user row. Go to friendList column. Return name of each friends whose name is in that array?

Currently I am doing this:

```
- (PFQuery *)queryForTable {

    //Query user's friend request
    PFQuery *query =  [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friends"];
    [query whereKey:@"user" equalTo:[PFUser currentUser]];
    [query includeKey:@"receivedRequest"];
    return query;
}
```

This is returning only Id of the use's added my current user. I need their name from _User table.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what I'd do:

(1) the User class ought to be about the user's relationship with the app, a place for data that's just between the user and the app.

(2) For data that users want to share, have a Persona class that has an image, nickname, etc.  Persona should contain a pointer to User and vice versa.

(3) Personae (Personas in common usage) make friend invitations and become friends.

(4) arrays of string object ids = bad, arrays of pointers = good.  In fact, I can't think of a circumstance where I'd prefer a string object id over a pointer.

(5) A FriendInvitation ought to be its own object, where inviter and invitee are pointers to Persona.

(6) A friendship is a bilateral and symmetrical relationship (at least we always hope they are).   A good representation for that might be a Friendship class that has *an array* of pointers to exactly two Persona objects.

Here are a few functions, given a data model:

Persona has a pointer to User, call it '`user`', and User has a `persona` pointer.  FriendInvitation has an `inviter` and `invitee`, both pointers to Persona.  Friendship has an array of two pointers to Persona, call it `friends`

```
// get the current user's FriendInvitations
- (void)friendInvitationsWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))completion {
    PFObject *persona = [PFUser currentUser][@"persona"];
    PFQuery *query =  [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"FriendInvitation"];
    [query whereKey:@"invitee" equalTo:persona];
    [query includeKey:@"inviter"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
}

// get the current user's friendships
// remember, these are not the friends, but the objects that record pairings of friends.
// see the next function for the friends
- (void)friendshipsWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))completion {
    PFObject *persona = [PFUser currentUser][@"persona"];
    PFQuery *query =  [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"Friendship"];
    [query whereKey:@"friends" equalTo:persona];
    [query includeKey:@"friends"];
    [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
}

// get the current user's friends' personae
- (void)friendsWithCompletion:(void (^)(NSArray *, NSError *))completion {
    PFObject *persona = [PFUser currentUser][@"persona"];
    [self friendshipsWithCompletion:^(NSArray *friendships, NSError *error) {
        if (!error) {
            NSMutableArray *result = [@[] mutableCopy];
            for (PFObject *friendship in friendships) {
                NSArray *friends = friendship[@"friends"];
                NSInteger indexOfFriend = ([friends indexOfObject:persona] == 0)? 1 : 0;
                [result addObject:friends[indexOfFriend]];
            }
            completion(result, nil);
        } else {
            completion(nil, error);
        }
    }];
}

// agree to be friends with someone
- (void)becomeFriendsWith:(PFObject *)friend completion:(void (^)(BOOL, NSError *))completion {
    PFObject *persona = [PFUser currentUser][@"persona"];
    PFObject *friendship = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"Friendship"];
    friendship[@"friends"] = @[ persona, friend ];
    [friendship saveInBackgroundWithBlock:completion];
}

// we could go on, but this should convey the basic ideas
```

Answer (score 1):

Friends table should not have arrays, but single IDs (actually pointers). So for every incoming request or friendship, there should be a single, separate entry on the database. So your Friends object (or for a better name, Relationship, or Friendship, but that's my personal preference of course) should roughly have following properties:

- first (_User)
- second (_User)
- type (String. Possible values: 'friends' or 'request', maybe even 'blocked')

And for every accepted request, make sure you are creating two entries, one with first=user1/second=user2 and one with first=user2/second=user1. While you could technically go without making double entries, it will just complicate things in the long run, making everything harder to maintain.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but if number of users increase. Let's say a user has 1000 friends. dose n't effect the query time? I am looking for some ways to decrease overhead?

Comment: I probably should have mentioned why I suggested an array on the friendship table rather than two columns, one for each end of the relationship:  for a small benefit, so we won't need two queries: currentUser == first  OR currentUser == second.  A small benefit, and no harm (that I can think of).  Can you explain why using two columns is better?

Comment: @Bernard more users, friendships, etc, will cause this idea to consume more resources, as it will mine.  If you're optimizing only for fetching a user's friends, then an array attached to a user is more efficient than the "join-table" (parse relation equivalent) suggested here.  I think you should go for something like this --solid and not-absurd at scale, then *discover empirically* where to improve.  It will be a happy day when you have 100K users and need to rebuild because its slowing down.

Comment: @danh for a better/solid model. if we use arrays, we are using an array for exactly two items, where two separate columns would make the database less prone to errors. just a stability issue. other than that, it will overcomplicate things like friend requests, blocked users etc as they'll need an extra table of their own. in addition, my method is also single query, not double query, and we will only be doing a double operation when creating a new friendship, which, I think is acceptable. reading friendship is single query.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu - regarding "less prone to errors"... a developer might forget to set "first" or "second" columns as easily as she could forget to fill the array.  The array has an extra error mode since it can allow more than two elements.  Maybe this is a "friendship circle" feature?  If not, then it's a problem easily caught in beforeSave.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu - regarding "overcomplicate things... they'll need an extra table":  To support this, you'd have to demonstrate that an array of two items requires a new table somewhere else and two columns do not.   That just cannot be the case.  The two approaches are equivalent with respect to the rest of the data model.

Comment: @CanPoyrazoğlu - regarding "mine is also a single query"... I'm afraid that's exactly where you're mistaken.  Try to write a "get friends" query and include it in your answer.  Remember that it is unknown whether the current user is saved in the "first" or "second" columns of the friendship objects.

Comment: @danh 1: I highly doubt putting friendships in an array is a good idea. 2: About the extra columns case I was clearly referring to your answer. 3: I think you haven't understood what meant. Having two complimentary entries means that person1 is guaranteed to be first user at one point while person2 is guaranteed to be second user. there will also exist an exact opposite of this, so it's up to you which one to query.