# Swift - Parse - Friend list - Possibility to create groups of friends

Tags: swift, user-interface, parse-platform, swift3

Could someone give me a link (*github/gitlab*) of a swift projet which show the possibility of managing Users on **Parse**.

For example , I would like for a user (who have 15 friends):

- to create a group with 5 friends for example (the user could add a name for this group)
- to delete if necessary the group
- to send a message(textfield) to a group
- to send a message (textfield) to a user

For the UI, I would like if it exists, to manager user like the Springboard (having the picture of user in round), and when you longpress on it, you have a cross to delete /and 'block sign' to block user.
And the user could drag/drop other user on his friend list to create a group (like on the Springboard when you create a group of app)

Thanks for helping me !

Have a nice day!

Comment: Isn't parse.com out of order?

Comment: Yes but you can easily setup a local parse server or try with aws for example!

Answer (score 0):

I've not come across such framework for parse/swift. I think you need to build it yourself.

This might help you in the direction:

- Friend/de-friend people: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32557977/3314336 & 
  [Parse Swift: User relations with a "friends request"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33685487/parse-swift-user-relations-with-a-friends-request)
- Send messages framework: https://github.com/slackhq/SlackTextViewController

Comment: Thanks @LenD!
But I am surprised that nobody has come to this subject before :)

It's basicaly managing a group of friends to send them a group message or a picture or a video (With Parse).

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is pretty general and extensive. You could use Roles and Relations to manage friend groups. You could have Group objects, give them an owner, and a relation for all the members of the group.

For chat, I'd recommend not trying to just build that directly into Parse. Twilio recently released their Programmable Chat feature, which is awesome. Sounds like it'd be beneficial for you to use that.

Comment: Thanks for replying! Have you seen any project with groups/friends (for eg to send pictures)?